# Backbone: When i write an url in browser's url bar its goes directly to server, some config needed?

Tags: routes, backbone.js, coffeescript

The site is working ok. It is routing urls ok when i click on links or by using the `.navigate()` function.

But... if i write the URL in the browser's url bar (tried with chrome / firefox) i get a response from the server: Cannot `GET /route` (i'm using express node.js server).

**Example:**
I have the site at localhost:3333, if i write localhost:3333/favorites i get this response: `Cannot GET /favorites`.

But if i click on a link that has an event handler that calls a .navigate() function the view is displayed and the url bar get's updated to "localhost:3333/favorites"! Some idea?

I tried with: `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})` and `Backbone.history.start()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as to be expected. Your server needs to support all the same routes and return the HTML/JS/etc regardless. Once the page has rendered backbone will register the route and render the appropriate view.